# Import a local JSON file in your pc to your basic HTML page and display it's content using Chart.js API

Tags: javascript, web-development, json-ld

Import a local JSON file in your pc to your basic HTML page and display it's content using Chart.js API.

Comment: I closed this because it isn't a question.   Please edit your post to add more details.  What are you trying to do?  Do you have a question about it?